# Objective-c sort array by last object

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have problem with sort array of arrays. I already build method to sort but it not work properly. I mean that final table should be sorted by last element, descending using the last element.

My method:

```
static NSInteger order (id a, id b, void* context) 
        {
        NSNumber* catA = [a lastObject];
        NSNumber* catB = [b lastObject];
        return [ catB compare: catA];
        }
```

And call it by:

```
[ array sortUsingFunction:order context:NULL];
```

And  my array is sort that:

```
{1,9}
{1,6}
{1,5}
{2,2}
{0,18}
{12, 10}
{9,1}
```

Where is problem?

Comment: You need to tell us more about the contents of `array`.

Comment: you're doing reverse sorting because you compare catA to catB, not vice versa (try `return [catA compare:catB]`.

Comment: What do you mean by: *"not work properly"*? What's the result you want to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say exactly what is wrong with the array after you sort it.  I see two possible problems.

1. As Eimantas says in his comment, you are sorting the array in reverse order (highest to lowest).  If you want to sort lowest to highest, you need to say `return [catA compare:catB]`.
2. It looks like the elements of `catA` and `catB` are strings, not numbers, so you are sorting them as strings.  The string '10' is less than the string '9', but the number 10 is greater than the number 9.  Even though you are casting the elements to `NSNumber`, that does not change the type of the underlying object, which is still `NSString`.

You can sort them as numbers this way:

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    return [[a lastObject] intValue] - [[b lastObject] intValue];
}]
```

But it might be better to convert the strings to number objects before sorting the array:

```
for (NSMutableArray *element in array) {
    [element replaceObjectAtIndex:(element.count - 1)
        withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[element.lastObject intValue]]];
}

[array sortUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    return [[a lastObject] intValue] - [[b lastObject] intValue];
}]
```

Comment: You probably mean `return [[a lastObject] intValue] - [[a lastObject] intValue];`. His array contains arrays of Strings in the second case you mentioned.

Comment: It's array of array (something like matrix NxM), and I want to sort the array by last object from greatest to the least (revers order). OK I check this and actually it was NSMutableString i change this for NSNumber. thx for all